# How to override the height of parent node using CSS?

Tags: html, css, chat

I'm writing an online chatting widget and I plan to design it as Facebook's.
In my page, a bar is fixed on the bottom, and every chat rooms are contained in that bar.
While the bar's height is fixed, the chat rooms cannot extend its height outside the bar.

Is there any method to achieve this? I have used z-index, !important, and overflow, but all failed.

CSS:

```
#SNbar {    
    background-color: rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.80);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 900;
    overflow: visible;   
}

#chatSessions { 
    position: relative;  
    bottom: 0;    
    float:right;
    z-index: 901;
}

.chatSession {
    /*
    position: fixed;  
    bottom: 0; 
    */ 
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 260px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 999;
}

.CStitle {     
    height: 25px;   
    background-color:#3B5998;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.CStitle .titleText{
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none; 
    line-height:2em;
}

.CSbody {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1.0;
    display: none;
    height: 0 !important;
}

.opened{
    min-height: 260px !important;
    display: block;
}

.CSMsgContainer {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 210px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="SNbar">      
    <div id="chatSessions">
        <div class="chatSession" id="Div4">
            <div class="CStitle" onclick="toggleChatSession(this)"><span class="titleText">Title (With Whom)</span> </div>
            <div class="CSbody">
                <div class="CSMsgContainer">
                    <div class="message">b: test1</div>
                    <div class="message">b: this is used to test css</div>
                    <div class="message">a: This may be help</div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatSession" id="Div8">
            <div class="CStitle" onclick="toggleChatSession(this)"><span class="titleText">Title (With Whom)</span></div>
            <div class="CSbody">
                <div class="CSMsgContainer">
                    <div id="Div9" class="message">d: hi C!!</div>
                    <div id="Div10" class="message">c: Hello D~~</div>
                    <div id="Div11" class="message">
                        c: We are the second chat session
                    </div>                  
                 </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, from this when you click on .CStitle, you are toggling the CSbody. So for this, you can set position relative to chatSession class and to the CSbody, give position absolute.

```
.chatSession {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 260px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 999;
}

.CStitle {     
    height: 25px;   
    background-color:#3B5998;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.CSbody {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1.0;
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    bottom:25px;
}

.opened{
    min-height: 260px;
    display: block;
}

.CSMsgContainer {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 210px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Now the CSbody can extend as my desired way. But the CStitle still sticks on there. I tried to position:absolute on CStitle, but this would make chatboxes to overlap. I also add a hidden sibling of CStitle and CSbody, but it did not help, either.

Answer (score 2):

position:absolute for the inner container is what you want. Then you can put it anywhere you want. Best is probably to set position:relative to the parent container, so that the position of the inner containers will using the parent as "base".

Comment: This method makes chatbox extend, but the outer container also extend to the height of the inner one. I want the SNbar sticking on the bottom of screen with its height fixed, so position:fixed is needed.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this
    #SNbar {
    height: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
    }